# Как получить имя кампании Adwords из api Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Исходя из документации [dimensions-metrics-explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/)

из api GA можно взять все основные  показатели по кампаниям AdWords, но ничего нет, что бы дёрнуть имя кампании. 
Вообще список похоже не полный, например там нет ga:clientId, но api отдаёт эту метрику. Пробовал указывать в запросе ga:adwordsCampaigName , ga:CampaignName, но выдает ошибку . Неужели нет возможности дернуть имя кампании??

Answer (score 0):

Ответ - ga:campaign , правда это измерение отдает все кампании, а не только эдвордс и если источник не эдвордс , оно принимает значение метки utm_campaign